# jQuery getting value from element with appended HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am appending a table with a drag and drop library for uploading files. However when a file is dropped, I need to create a name and description for this file. However, I cant seem to get the element from the text box when someone writes in the name.

This is the code and my attempt.

```
$.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
         $('#TestTable > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td>' + file.name + '</td><td><input id="file-upload-title' + file.name + '" type="text"></td></tr>');

            data.context = $('<button/>').text('Upload')
            .addClass("btn btn-primary start")
            .appendTo('#TestTable > tbody:last-child')
            .click(function () {
                    // This is the problem
                   alert($('#file-upload-title' + file.name).val()); = undefined
            });

        });
```

You can see when I append the table I use a unique ID for the `file-upload-title` input text object (in case there are many files)

How can I get the value from writing the HTML after the document has loaded?

**Edit**

There is a object present for `$('#file-upload-title' + file.name)` but not `val()`

Thanks

Comment: you are not getting elements because you are appending this element, so these element are not loaded in document when page loads, you need to bind this element in document ready, then this will work..  read [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Comment: would be nice to have a demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of hacking together a selector you can use the `this` keyword to reference the element which raised the event. From there you can use DOM traversal methods to find the related `input`. You haven't shown your HTML so I can't give you a specific example, but it would be something like this:

```
// your code...
.click(function () {
    var $input = $(this).closest('tr').find('input');
    console.log($input.val());
});
```

Comment: OK I get what you are saying, though `this` would be the button so I would to use `find` and `get` to find the element right?

Comment: That's right. I can't see where the button is placed in relation to the input to give you a specific example though.

Comment: Thanks Rory, before you edited I saw I can get to the input type via the developer console. thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: No problem, glad to help